How to correctly call a function in PostgreSQL
I have created a function that does not give any errors itself but when calling it I get an error. I know I technically don't need a function but for my scenario I need to be using one.
The error:
QUERY "SELECT (show_date) FROM show" returned more than one row.
CONTEXT: PL/PGSql function change_data_type() line 3 at RETURN
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_data_type()
RETURNS date as $$
BEGIN
    RETURN DATE(show_date) FROM show;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT change_data_type();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_data_type()
RETURNS TABLE(dt date) 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
as $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT show_date::date FROM show;
END;
$$ ;

create table show(show_date timestamp);
insert into show values (now()), (now() - '1 day'::interval), (now() + '45 mins'::interval);

select * from show;
         show_date          
----------------------------
 2024-05-04 08:37:09.334147
 2024-05-03 08:37:09.334147
 2024-05-04 09:22:09.334147


select * from change_data_type();
 dt     
------------
 2024-05-04
 2024-05-03
 2024-05-04


See:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html

When a PL/pgSQL function is declared to return SETOF sometype, the procedure to follow is slightly different. In that case, the individual items to return are specified by a sequence of RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY commands, and then a final RETURN command with no argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing. RETURN NEXT can be used with both scalar and composite data types; with a composite result type, an entire “table” of results will be returned. RETURN QUERY appends the results of executing a query to the function's result set. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY can be freely intermixed in a single set-returning function, in which case their results will be concatenated.


RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY do not actually return from the function — they simply append zero or more rows to the function's result set. Execution then continues with the next statement in the PL/pgSQL function. As successive RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY commands are executed, the result set is built up. A final RETURN, which should have no argument, causes control to exit the function (or you can just let control reach the end of the function).


create table show(show_date DATE);
INSERT INTO show values (now());

with one record:
SELECT change_data_type();

will not return an error
but with more than 1 record:
INSERT INTO show values (now());
SELECT change_data_type();

it will, see: DBFIDDLE
ERROR:  query returned more than one row
CONTEXT:  query: DATE(show_date) FROM show
PL/pgSQL function change_data_type() line 3 at RETURN

